# Pass certificate to requests.post from s3 bucket in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am calling the api and want to send certificate along with it like this:

```
 response = requests.post(url,cert=('pem_cert.pem', 'key_cert.key'), headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response)
```

Now, both pem_cert.pem and key_cert.key files are present in the local directory so it's work well, but now I want to store those certificate to S3 bucket and use it here, how can I do it?

1. I tried to place S3 URI but it can't find it, permission is there
2. I read the file from S3 bucket and passed the content directly but it's not worked.

Please help me with this.

Also I have tried to copy those file locally using:

```
    S3_BUCKET = 'test-bucket'
    object_key = "certificates/transport.key"  
    key_content = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=object_key)["Body"].read()
key_cert = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.key')
    key_cert.write(key_content)
```

and then passing it to the request as:

```
 response = requests.post(url,cert=(pem_cert.name, key_cert.name), headers=headers, data=payload)
```

and I get max retry error:

```
"errorMessage": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='abc.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
```

Comment: requests only takes a path to a local file for the cert, so you'll need to download both files to `/tmp` and point it to the local copies to use.

Comment: I have tried this, getting max request error, updated the question with the same

Comment: The max request error suggests that you copies the files to /tmp as string. Copy them as bytes, see my suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

To read your pem and cert file from an S3 bucket you can copy them into lambda temp storage /tmp and use it from there like it was a file on your local hard disk.
*When you copy from S3 to /tmp just make sure you copy as binary file and not as a string as it won't work.*

```
import json
import requests
import boto3 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    #GET CERT FROM BUCKET
    bucket = 'MyBucketWithCerts'
    pem_key = 'MyCert.pem'
    key_key = 'MyPrivateKey.key'

    #Get the key and cert object
    pem_response= s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=pem_key)
    key_response= s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key_key)

    PemContent = pem_response['Body'].read()
    KeyContent = key_response['Body'].read()
    
    #This is the path you'll use in lambda's temp storage
    Pemfile_path = '/tmp/MyCert.pem'
    Keyfile_path = '/tmp/MyPrivateKey.key'

    #Now create the files in lambda's tmp folder
    with open(Pemfile_path, "wb") as Pembinary_file:
        Pembinary_file.write(PemContent)  

    with open(Keyfile_path, "wb") as Keybinary_file:
        Keybinary_file.write(KeyContent)  

    #IMPORTANT, copy them as bytes not as string
    # This won't work

    # tmpPemFile = open(Pemfile_path, "a")
    # tmpPemFile.write(PemContent)
    # tmpPemFile.close()

    #Now you can do your request referencing your temp lambda files
    x = requests.post('MyURL', data=your_data, headers=your_headers,cert=(Pemfile_path,Keyfile_path))
    print("RESPONSE -> " + json.dumps(x.text))
```